# How do I get the combined output which has | (pipeline) in output

Tags: sed

I have a file with name A.txt
I have to create a file B.txt such that it has some text written in starting,with a pipeline symbol besides it,following with the no of lines in file A (10 lines here in this example) and then the contents of file A.

Note:I have to do it as easily as possible in a single line command.

Output:

```
Some text | 10
(Contents of file A)
```

I tried this(not including pipeline symbol) but didn't work:

```
(echo 'Some Text'; 
sed -i 1,10d A.txt ; 
wc -l A.txt ;cat A.txt) 
>> B.txt
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"? Your example looks mostly functional.

Comment: It deleted the contents of file A but didn't copy those contents to file B. Also,I'm not knowing how to get the pipelines symbol in the output .

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i 1,10d A.txt` deletes lines 1 through 10 from A.txt *but doesn't print anything.* `cat`ting the file afterwards (even within the same sub-shell) will print the *modified* contents of the file, not the original.

Comment: Yes correct,that's why at the end it is followed by _>>B.txt_ to redirect whole output of process to B.txt

Answer (score 2):

If there are only 10 lines in `A.txt`, and you deleted those lines with `sed`, then the following `cat A.txt` will have no output, and `wc` will report 0 lines.

You probably want something like:

```
(
echo "Some text | $(wc -l < A.txt)"
cat A.txt
) > B.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Olorin for the clarification,the  command provided was partially correct. In the output it is showing as _A.txt_ besides the number of lines (10 here).How do I delete the _A.txt_ thing in the output

Comment: @imabeast `wc -l < A.txt` instead of `wc -l A.txt` should do that

Comment: One more doubt Olorin, is the $ operator really needed ? What difference does $ really making over here?

Comment: It's not just `$`, it's `$( )`, or [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst). If you don't use it, then you'll have to do something to avoid a newline after `Some text |`, either `echo -n` or `printf`. I don't think there's any benefit in using those instead of command substitution.

Comment: Learnt something new today, thanks to  you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
lines=$( wc -l A.txt ) ; printf "Some Text | %s\n" ${lines%% *} > B.txt ; cat A.txt  >> B.txt
```

1. The output of `wc` includes the file's name, so it needs to be removed, which is done using the shell's native suffix removal feature `${var%%glob}`.
2. I have a personal preference to default to use `printf` instead of `echo` because `echo` has cases where it misbehaves.
3. Performing the output redirection twice ensures that the output file doesn't include data from a prior run of the one-liner; the first redirection `>` overwrites any prior version.